# Set ANT property from the response of a HTTP GET request

Tags: java, http, properties, ant, get

I am new to ANT and I need to get a way to read the output of a HTTP GET request into a property so I can use it later in the build script.

I tried using https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html but found no parameters available. I am using ant 1.9.6 and latest ant contrib version

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [<loadresource>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) task with a nested [<url>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#url) resource:

```xml
<loadresource property="content">
    <url url="https://google.com"/>
</loadresource>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!
Note: If using GET parameters, make sure to replace & with &amp; entity.

Comment: Also, if you need a single line, striping line breaks can be done easily by inserting the following <filterchain><striplinebreaks/></filterchain>, next to url tag.